# Selectively Pull HTML website book with ToC Links in Frames into an Epub? excluding library links & other books

Tags: epub, conversion, html, website

This is related, but has some issues in working.   [How can I convert an HTML site into an ebook?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-i-convert-an-html-site-into-an-ebook?newreg=bc7fdd7a8cb14584a70693f621bb703e)

- Top > Website Menu
- Left Frame > Table of Contents (Multi Level Nested Tree with JScript I think)
- Right Frame > Content relevant to Link from ToC clicked

Now, when using one of the existing "wget/ httrack" downloaders, I end up getting 2 issues:

- The generated offline webpage links still try to pop open the pages in a frame
- End up getting Superset pages outside of the said book. How could one exclude them?

My guess is it needs a different type / restricted website downloader / ripper / scraper. Once it does its deed, we could probably use Calibre.

PS: Someone please embed them - Having some browser Image dialog issues:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDEbz.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSWL5.jpg

Comment: You should probably try to better explain your quesiton, it is not easy to understand what you are willing to do.

Comment: @Sekhemty - I'll try to add some explanatory & indicative screenshots. Will create this weekend and update the question.